# How do I write to a 2D array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am having trouble using 2D arrays.

I am using an array of arrays of strings.

Each line of the input file contains two strings and each line needs to be one array.

Below is my code and the text from codons.txt. My code has a few extra cout commands for debugging. When I run it, it does not display the second string.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cctype>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int CODONSLENGTH=64;
    string codons[CODONSLENGTH][2];
    ifstream infile;
    //void readRNACodonTable(string [][2]);

    //readRNACodonTable(codons);

    infile.open("codons.txt");
    if (!infile.is_open()){
        cout << "ERROR: Coudn't open input file.";
        exit(1);
    }

    for (int i=0; i < CODONSLENGTH && !infile.eof(); i++) {
        cout << "DEGUG: start iteration " << i << endl;
        infile >> codons[i][0] >> codons[i][1];
        cout << "DEBUG: " << codons[i][0] << " " << codons[i][2] <<
        endl;
    }
    infile.close();

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Here is codons.txt:

```
GCU A
GCC A
GCA A
GCG A
CGU R
CGC R
CGA R
CGG R
AGA R
AGG R
AAU N
AAC N
GAU D
GAC D
UGU C
UGC C
CAA Q
CAG Q
GAA E
GAG E
GGU G
GGC G
GGA G
GGG G
CAU H
CAC H
AUU I
AUC I
AUA I
UUA L
UUG L
CUU L
CUC L
CUA L
CUG L
AAA K
AAG K
AUG M
UUU F
UUC F
CCU P
CCC P
CCA P
CCG P
UCU S
UCC S
UCA S
UCG S
AGU S
AGC S
ACU T
ACC T
ACA T
ACG T
UGG W
UAU Y
UAC Y
GUU V
GUC V
GUA V
GUG V
```

Comment: You are using `<< codons[i][2]`. That should be `<< codons[i][1]`.

Comment: Voting to close. Problem caused by a typo.

Comment: Yep. It was caused by a typo, but I don't have enough reputation to close the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a typo in your debug output, the subscript of the second string is `2` but it should be `1` (as indices start from `0`, the second object is indexed at `1`, like you did in the reading line).

```
for (int i=0; i < CODONSLENGTH && !infile.eof(); i++) {
    cout << "DEGUG: start iteration " << i << endl;
    infile >> codons[i][0] >> codons[i][1];
    cout << "DEBUG: " << codons[i][0] << " " << codons[i][1] << endl; // <-- HERE
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're writing to `codons[i][1]` but reading from `codons[i][2]`.